# highcharts hovering effect issue

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to use  semi circle donuts  Highchart in my project. I want to use multi-rings in this high-chart.

But I am facing hovering issue when I hover over the outer ring it highlights fine but when I hover over the inner ring it is  highlighting both of the rings .

I removed the extra shadow with this -

```
        states: {
            hover:  {
                halo: false
                    }
               }

  }
```

but could not make outer-ring non-highlight.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s4bgyjto/)

When I hover over the inner ring only, only the inner ring should highlight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable `inactive` state for the second series:

```
series: [...,
    {
        ...,
        states: {
            inactive: {
                opacity: 1
            }
        }
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/qvyd2urb/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.states.inactive

Comment: thanks for this 
have one more question  suppose for each ring i have three values so can I create a legend which will highlight the first value(also secone and third)  of both of the ring 

showInlegend : true created 6 legends for each ring I want only three .
one for one value only

https://jsfiddle.net/cvne5z8p/

Comment: Hi @Anurag Pandey, Please check this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/befp0v6n/ Is this the result you wanted to achieve?

Comment: hi thanks that's exactly what I wanted you are great :)

Comment: hi @ppotcazek I am now facing a different scenario so suppose for one of the ring I dont have any data but I still want to show the ring with No data and in this scenario if I then hover over legend then only the ring with data should toggle highlight for different values and the ring with NO Data should remain the same .

the issue is No data ring still toggling the highlight .
as I am working on a secured project can post too much of code ..
something like this.
https://jsfiddle.net/apenvt5h/

Comment: Hi @Anurag Pandey, Could you create another question with `highcharts` tag?

Answer (score 2):

Two pie charts just overlaps. Try to play with:

- innerSize - to increase empty center spacing
- center - change slightly position of the chart
- size - increase size of the chart

Finally try to modify the settings of first chart into:

```
series: [{
     type: 'pie',
     name: 'Browser share',
     innerSize: '92%',
     center: ['50%', '75%'],
     size: '120%',
     ...
}]
```

Should solve the issue.

[Working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-field-17p42?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: hey thanks followed your approach it worked fine !!